# how to make if statement from a html table index - x then create new table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

guy's i need your help.
i try to make an if statement from my html table value index-x (x = index of the column )
i have try to make a code to recreate the table into an array. and it working well. but i don't know how to make the if statement inside there.

i want to put an if statement like this.
checking the value of `.table-bordered` index[4]. when it has value inside the range it will give a callback creating new `td` with the value that it was set in the callback

the range like this

1. if `.table-bordered` index[4] value is `1000<index[4]<=10000` then callback 10000
2. if `.table-bordered` index[4] value is `10000<index[4]<=20000` then callback 20000
3. if `.table-bordered` index[4] value is `20000<index[4]<=40000` then callback 37500

```js
// JavaScript Document
//Note:
//The IF condition like this
//a=1000; b=10000; c= 20000; d=45000 and x as the value
//(a> x <b) ; (b> x <=c); (c> x <=d); (x>d)
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#display_data').on("click", function(e) {
    var myTableArray = [];
    $(".table-bordered tr").each(function() {
      var tdValue = ($(this).find("td:eq(4)").text());
   var a= "1.000";
   var b= "10.000";
   var c= "20.000";
   var d= "45.000";
   
   var callback1="10.000";
   var callback2="20.000";
   var callback3="37.500";
   var callback4="45.000";
       if (tdValue > a && tdValue <= b) { //this if condition not getting the value
        console.log(callback1);
      } else if (tdValue > b && tdValue <= c) {
        console.log(callback2);
      } else if (tdValue > c && tdValue <= d) {
        console.log(callback3);
      } else {
        console.log('Your value is ' + tdValue);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>WCB</td>
<td>101</td>
<td>5006538574</td>
<td>10.08.2017</td>
<td>30.830</td>
<td>KG</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>WCB</td>
<td>101</td>
<td>5006539622</td>
<td>10.08.2017</td>
<td>21.080</td>
<td>KG</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>WCB</td>
<td>101</td>
<td>5006539759</td>
<td>10.08.2017</td>
<td>40.990</td>
<td>KG</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button type="submit" id="#display_data" class="btn btn-primary">Upload File</button>
```

please someone help me..
just give me one example with one if function there. i'm stuck here

Comment: Keep in mind that in your example, all values in column 4 are less than 1000, due to the decimal separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code, to help you out. You need to use `"td:eq(4)"` to get the value/text and use it for comparison:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#display_data').on("click", function(e) {
    var myTableArray = [];
    $(".table-bordered tr").each(function() {
      var tdValue = parseFloat($(this).find("td:eq(4)").text());
      console.log(tdValue)
      if (tdValue > 1000 && tdValue <= 10000) {
        console.log('This is 10000');
      } else if (tdValue > 10000 && tdValue <= 20000) {
        console.log('This is 20000');
      } else {
        console.log('Your value is ' + tdValue);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>WCB</td>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>5006538574</td>
      <td>10.08.2017</td>
      <td>30.830</td>
      <td>KG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>WCB</td>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>5006539622</td>
      <td>10.08.2017</td>
      <td>21.080</td>
      <td>KG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>WCB</td>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>5006539759</td>
      <td>10.08.2017</td>
      <td>40.990</td>
      <td>KG</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="submit" id="display_data" class="btn btn-primary">Upload File</button>
```

Comment: btw.. i try to chage your code and add a `var` for define the value of the callback after `if function is true` why the console log data give me value of my table data index [4]?

Comment: If you are changing the value of that `td`, you need to use that variable or get the value again using `$(this).find("td:eq(4)").text()`. What value are you trying to change? Also, your values are way lesser than 1000, in the given example.

Comment: oh.. like that..
@Milan Chheda thx for your answer.
that give me an inspiration for the next step.
thx a lot

Comment: btw bro.. can i ask. i got wrong catch the range. the range inside `if` is not working.

Comment: Sorry, can't understand, please elaborate.

Comment: w8 i will editing my code to my new code inspire from you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151820/discussion-between-milan-chheda-and-minervaz-mine).

Comment: i think i write right syntax for that. but why the 1st `if` condition can't get the condition